# Can not display MySQL data decimal(16,2) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQL data base that has a cell in a record called balance. The db shows it is stored as a decimal(16,2). When I try to display the vale of the record with echo $row["balance"]; In PHP, it display nothing at all. Can you please point me in the right direction. Thanks you.

$sql = "SELECT id, email, username  FROM ppb_users WHERE id = '$USERIDX'   ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
   {
    //// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       {
         echo "<br> id: " . $row["id"] . "<br> email: " . $row["email"] . "<br> username: " . $row["username"] . "<br> Ballance: " . $row["balance"] ."<br>";           
         
         $UserEmail = $row["email"];
         $balancex = $row["balance"]; 
       }
   } 
else 
   {
     echo " 0 results <br><br>";
   }
```

$conn->close();

Comment: Hi @Sean Moore! Can you post the `SELECT Statement` you used? And the `CREATE Statement` and `INSERT into` statements for your table and Provide as sample data in your question? Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: I just edited the post to show the full code. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, it would seem I had one of those moments in where when it is over and you realize what you did, how small you feel. I did not add balance to the SQL se3lect line. Uggg! Soryy.